# Proof Verification: Order/Cardinality of a coset

Tags: group-theory, functions, proof-verification, alternative-proof

For  G a group and H a subgroup of G, I'm required to show that 
$|aH| = |bH|$ for all $a,b\epsilon G$

Proof:
Define a function $f:aH\to bH$ such that
$f(ah) = bh$ for some $h\epsilon H$
Then we show, f is 1-1 and onto, i.e. f is a bijection
1) f is 1-1:
let $f(ah)=f(h')$
then $bh = bh'$
multiplying by $b^{-1}$ to the left we get
$ h= h'$
Hence, f is injective

2) I have to show that f is onto but I don't know how.
Can anyone let me know as well as verify the aforementioned proof for injectivity of f?

Answer (score 1):

One-one: If $f(ah)=f(ah')$, then $bh=bh'$ and the cancellation property gives $h=h'$.

Onto: For all $bh\in bH$, $f(ah)=bh$. This covers every element of $bH$.

Comment: Is this statement sufficient? Also, is my injectivity proof alright and would this be good enough to conclude that $|aH| = |bH|$

Comment: I think your proof should've stated $f(ah)=f(ah')$ instead of $f(ah)=f(h')$. Then the rest works out. Since $f$ is bijective, the cosets must have the same cardinality. This is a basic property of set theory.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was a typing error. Thanks!